# how can i freely sort cards in drag and drop layout - jquery bootstrap - where multiple cards can be placed in one row across multiple columns

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, sortablejs

i want to have drag and drop sortable layout for my bootstrap cards. i did dowith sortable jquery plugin but it is draging and droping in a row. i want that if i have card 1 that is bigger height col-6 size in one row, that i can have next to it in the same row card 3 and card 4 that are both col-3 size, so that card3 and card4 are one above eachother but both in the same row as card1.

[in this picure we see that card3 and 4 are in the same row as 7, which i like and want.. but on the example i want also that card 1 has next card 6 like it is but also card 7 belolow card 6 because there is space, or card 3 and card4 bellow card 6 in the same row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bUXz.png)

this is my code for the above picure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Display as grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
   
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="card">Card 1
          <p>
          some content so that the card is bigger
          </p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="card">Card 2</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="card">Card 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="card">Card 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card">Card 5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="card">Card 6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="card">Card 7</div>
        </div>
        </div>
  
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
  <script>
   
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".row").sortable({
        connectWith: ".row"
      }).disableSelection();
    });
  </script>
```

--- i want to freely move cards in columns and rows where there is space for the specific card, but the size of columns for the cards doesnt change. so i want - that card 1 has next card 6 like it is but also card 7 belolow card 6 because there is space, or card 3 and card4 bellow card 6 in the same row